# H bridge circuit using FAN7392

Tags: gate-driving, igbt

[image]

YELLOW- LOW IN

RED -   HI IN

BLUE - LOW SIDE OUTPUT

GREEN - HIGH SIDE OUTPUT

I have designed a H bridge circuit using FAN7392 & 25N120NDH IGBT. The voltage I want to switch for now is 24 volt DC. It’s designed for switching 400V DC.

So right now the bootstarp capacitor is 0.33 uF tantalum cap (In schematic it is 10uF). Switching frequency is 2.94 kHz. And its only driving the half bridge.

The problem is FAN7392 getting hot. FAN7392 is at 65 degree Celsius. And its drawing 0.00 to 0.80 A (varying with the PWM duty cycle). FAN7392 has been provided with 15V DC. And the logic level side has 5V DC. Shutdown pin is Grounded. And NO LOAD IS PRESENT ON THE AC SIDE (IGBT OUTPUT).

So the heat is normal for the current draw or I am doing  mistake?[image: Schemtic for H-BRIDGE]

Comment: Why 24V and IGBT?

Comment: Its just for testing the IGBT's. Thats why i want to test with 24 Volt 1st. Then i will apply 400 Volt  DC

Comment: NOTE IGBTs act ... Odd at very low voltage

Comment: 10k base to gnd resitors, they also leak current.  Where in the datasheet you have found they are needed?

Comment: I didnt found that in Datasheet. But in some blog i read that "Pulling Down the Gate help IGBT's from accidentally turn on during Startup". If you want i can remove them and let you know the result. But can it be the reson for FAN7392 Heating ?                                                                                            
                                                     
  http://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2012/10/magic-of-knowledge.html,....

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I don't see any issue with pull-down resistors. 10 k may be on the low end of the range though if that's what you meant.

Comment: I have removed the 10k PULL DOWN resistor. FAN7392 Now Drawing 0.00 to 0.71 Amps. FAN7392 is at 65 Degree Celsius

Comment: Your upper 10k were to GND instead of local-emitter

Comment: @JonRB Thank you for pointing out. I have now connected the Upper Pull Down to the Upper IGBT's Source... But my FAN7392 is still heating. Do you know what is the normal temperature of FAN7392 during Operation ??

Comment: @winny Thank you for editing the question.

Comment: Something is shorting/loading your Ch4 output. Look at the voltage level. Something is loading it. This would also explain why the driver is getting hot. Things only get hot when power is dissipated

Comment: By any chance are you using standard scope probes (ie ground clip) to monitor these signals ? You will be shorting the upper drivers via the scope as all probe clips are COMMON

Comment: Ok i am removing the probes.. Cause they all are connected to the same Ground. Lets see the result then

Comment: FAN7392 Still getting hot for unknown reason

Comment: You may have damaged the FAN7392. I have used the FAN7392 in designs and found it to be a relatively fragile device.  Take a look at page 14 of the datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FAN7392-D.pdf  Negative transients are extremely easy to induce with a poor layout in motor control designs.

Comment: @TuxRobotics Thanks for your Information

Comment: Try Increasing the gate resistance.